# Change of variable in double integrals $\iint_S f(x,y) \,dx \,dy$, where $S=\{(x,y)|x^2\leq y,-1 \leq x\leq 1\}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

**Problem**

> Express the double integral $\iint_S  f(x,y) \,dx \,dy$ as an iterated integral in polar coordinates, where $S=\{(x,y)|x^2\leq y,-1 \leq x\leq 1\}$.

**Doubt**

I have difficulty finding range of $r$ and $\theta$.

$r^2 \cos^2(\theta) \leq r \sin(\theta) \leq 1$

$-1 \leq r \sin(\theta) \leq 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may divide the area to three parts:
\begin{cases}
0\leq\theta\leq\dfrac{\pi}{4};\ 0\leq r\leq\sin\theta\sec^2\theta,\\
\dfrac{\pi}{4}\leq\theta\leq\dfrac{3\pi}{4};\ 0\leq r\leq\sec\theta,\\
\dfrac{3\pi}{4}\leq\theta\leq\pi;\ 0\leq r\leq\sin\theta\sec^2\theta.
\end{cases}
then
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{x^2}^{1} f(x,y)\ dy\ dx 
&=
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\int_{0}^{\sin\theta\sec^2\theta} f(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)\ r\ dr\ d\theta \\
&+
\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}\int_{0}^{\sec\theta} f(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)\ r\ dr\ d\theta \\
&+
\int_{3\pi/4}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\sin\theta\sec^2\theta} f(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)\ r\ dr\ d\theta
\end{align}